# PHP - IRC Private Message Function Help

Tags: php, irc

For some reason my bot wont private message a % of people on the IRC Channel. Here is my script:

```
<?php

$ircServer = "///";
$ircPort = "6667";
$ircChannel = "#bots";

set_time_limit(0);


$msg = $_POST['message'];
$pr = $_POST['percentage'];
$pr /= 100;

$ircSocket = fsockopen($ircServer, $ircPort, $eN, $eS);

if ($ircSocket)
{

    fwrite($ircSocket, "USER Lost rawr.test lol :code\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "NICK Rawr" . rand() . "\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "JOIN " . $ircChannel . "\n");

    while(1)
    {
        while($data = fgets($ircSocket, 128))
        {
            echo nl2br($data);
            flush();

            // Separate all data
            $exData = explode(' ', $data);

            // Send PONG back to the server
            if($exData[0] == "PING")
            {
                fwrite($ircSocket, "PONG ".$exData[1]."\n");
            }
}
    echo $eS . ": " . $eN;
}
shuffle($users);
$size = count($users);
$target = $size * $pr;
$target = $round($target);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++) {
    fwrite($ircSocket, "PRIVMSG " . $users[$i] . " :" . $msg . "\n");
}
}
?>
```

Here is the log on what I recieve:

```
:StatServ!stats@Mazzzzz.com PRIVMSG Rawr30566 :VERSION
```

I have even tried removing the Post data and replaced this part with this:

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];
```

With

```
$msg = hello;
```

The other people on the channel does not get a private message.

Comment: "$round" might be a problem :)

Comment: How sir? Please show me the exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your entire script? `$users` isn't set to anything; you probably meant to set it to an array of usernames. `$round` also isn't set; you probably meant to just call the built-in `round()` function. If you add a debugging line in the `for` loop you can at least tell which users (if any) should be getting messages:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++) {
    echo "Sending message to ${users[$i]}\n";
    fwrite($ircSocket, "PRIVMSG " . $users[$i] . " :" . $msg . "\n");
}
```

The IRC protocol stuff looks right. The receive log you were worried about doesn't have anything to do with it; StatServ on the IRC server is sending your bot a CTCP VERSION request. Normally clients respond with their name and version, and StatServ probably logs it so opers can see what clients are common on the network

Comment: It still does not work. My Mission is to write commands to the bot e.g. I enter command "Hello Get me" and it should send to the IRC bot to send the message to many other users on the IRC Channel. (Using the percentage system).

Comment: @Raymond You're missing the code that figures out the list of users in the room (you probably want to send a [NAMES message](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter4.html#c4_2_5) ), and you're missing something to deal with incoming messages -- come to think of it, you actually never break out of the `while(1)` loop, you just sit in it receiving messages forever without processing them

Comment: I carnt seem to figure it out, I have tried many methods. Maybe my PHP skills are not bril. Show me please.